# Rails 3: Trying to understand join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inner-join

I have a User class and a GroupUser class.  I'm trying to do a search by name of the users.  I tried following what I read on the joins, but I have something wrong.  Also I need to change my name portion of the query to a like instead of an equals

Here is the query I had initially built.

```
@users = GroupUser.joins(:users).where(:group_id => params[:group_id]).where(:users => {:name => params[:q]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@users = User.where("name ilike ? and id in (select distinct user_id from groups_users where group_id = ?)", "%#{params[:q]}%", params[:group_id])
```

Comment: I would rather go from the direction of GroupUsers as a user can be part of multiple groups.

Comment: From your original query I assume you want users, that belongs to specified group (params[:group_id]) and above query gives you that. If you go from GoupUser you will get array of GroupUser objects, not User.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work no matter what I did from the groupuser side, so I had to do it from the user side and it worked right away.  Something weird with my association or something.